# Advice for troubleshooting hard freezes associated with Safari? (Mid 2012 Retina Macbook Pro, 10.10.2)

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, performance

I have a Macbook Pro 10,1 (Mid 2012) running 10.10.2. Over the last few months, I have had issues with the system suddenly hanging - mouse won't move, keyboard does nothing, and the clock is stopped. I have to hold down the power button and restart the computer when this happens.

I have been experiencing these freezes ranging from daily to weekly. There is no consistent action that reproduces the freeze on demand. At some point in the last few months, though, I did switch to Safari from Chrome as my primary browser because the battery life seems so much better when using Safari. I've been doing a project over the last week that is dependent on Chrome, and as such haven't been using Safari, and have had no freezes. In retrospect, I think the freezes began happening when I started using Safari regularly.

I'd prefer to not have to choose between using Safari and having a stable system. Is anyone aware of issues like the one I'm experiencing? Any suggestions for further troubleshooting?

Edit 5/28/15:

I saved Console logs surrounding one of these freezes. When the computer froze, Safari was the frontmost app, and I was scrolling a page with 2-finger scroll on the trackpad. I then manually held down power to reboot.

```
5/28/15 7:17:00.130 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:00.130 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:05.290 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/28/15 7:17:05.451 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/28/15 7:17:06.541 PM locationd[81]: NETWORK: requery, 0, 0, 0, 0, 53, items, fQueryRetries, 0, fLastRetryTimestamp, 454546272.5
5/28/15 7:17:07.358 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:07.357 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:08.304 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:08.304 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:08.836 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:12.141 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:12.141 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:12.142 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:16.352 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:16.352 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:17.028 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
[the above line was repeated 57 times]
5/28/15 7:17:20.133 PM CalendarAgent[347]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
5/28/15 7:17:20.202 PM CalendarAgent[347]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
5/28/15 7:17:22.329 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:24.826 PM Mail[4385]: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:24.826 PM Mail[4385]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:24.975 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:24.975 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:30.784 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/28/15 7:17:30.904 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:30.903 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:31.880 PM Mail[4385]: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:31.880 PM Mail[4385]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:32.128 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:32.127 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:41.547 PM Mail[4385]: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:41.547 PM Mail[4385]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:41.619 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:41.619 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:43.930 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/28/15 7:17:44.871 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:44.870 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:45.276 PM Mail[4385]: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:45.276 PM Mail[4385]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:45.887 PM Mail[4385]: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:45.887 PM Mail[4385]: Failed to start the SASL connection
SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  Miscellaneous failure (see text (No credentials cache file found (negative cache))
5/28/15 7:17:47.141 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
[the above line was repeated 31 times]
5/28/15 7:17:49.080 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/28/15 7:17:50.308 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.309 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.309 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.310 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.310 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.311 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.312 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.312 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.312 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.313 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.344 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.345 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:50.345 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:52.927 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
5/28/15 7:17:53.320 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.321 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.321 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.322 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.322 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.322 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.323 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.323 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.323 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.324 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.325 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:53.375 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:54.251 PM sharingd[367]: 19:17:54.250 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:17:56.707 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.707 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.708 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.708 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.708 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.709 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.709 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.709 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.710 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.711 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.711 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.711 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.712 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.712 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.712 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.712 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.713 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.713 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:17:56.714 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:18:03.626 PM sharingd[367]: 19:18:03.626 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:18:12.101 PM sharingd[367]: 19:18:12.100 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:18:14.316 PM nsurlstoraged[344]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
5/28/15 7:18:21.589 PM sharingd[367]: 19:18:21.589 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:18:26.833 PM CalendarAgent[347]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
5/28/15 7:18:26.899 PM CalendarAgent[347]: [com.apple.calendar.store.log.caldav.coredav] [Refusing to parse response to PROPPATCH because of content-type: [text/html; charset=UTF-8].]
5/28/15 7:18:28.138 PM sharingd[367]: 19:18:28.137 : SDActivityAdvertiser::continuity:didFailToStartAdvertisingOfType:withError: Activity (The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.identityservices.error error 200.))
5/28/15 7:19:47.000 PM bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1432855187 0
```

Comment: Next time it freezes, note the time, then look up in Console for that time stamp and publish some 30 lines here.

Comment: I have had this exact same problem. I'm pretty sure it's also only been with Safari. I have a Late 2012 MBP Retina. This issue has persisted on two different SSDs with clean installs of Mavericks AND Yosemite. I've run every AST (and ASD OS and EFI) test multiple times, as well as Rember, Diskwarrior. Initially, during the thermal test in AST, I got an error (theta OH) and had to replace the heat sink, which enabled the computer to pass all tests. Yet the full system freeze occasionally persists. Mouse and screen freeze, and the computer auto-restarts after about 10-20 seconds. I'm going to no

Comment: Buscar웃SD, logs from the most recent crash were added to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue, MBPr 2012, the issue started as periodically, and now is very persistent, happens several times every day.

The solution is as stated to shut down the computer on the power button - the Microsoft Way!

I can tell that you'll see it more when you work with Safari, and uses HTTPS pages, or just has 5-6 pages opened at a time.

Hope that this can help someone to think about a solution, I've about using Firefox to see if the issue persist or not, to isolate the issue for Safari.

Since the issues is seen for Google Chrome, it might be interesting to hear if you uses HTTPS when it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably an extension. You probably already know that already, but there's no advice on the internet aside from my own that has worked for me.

```
cd ~/Library/Safari/Extensions
rm [plugins you KNOW did not come from apple]
```

The next part is key, in fact, this may be the only necessary step:

```
nano Extensions.plist
```

Remove everything between `<dict>` and `</dict>`.